# porting to Android: why am I getting "Can't create default XMLReader; is system property org.xml.sax.driver set?"?

Tags: android, sax, xmlreader

I am porting some Java code that worked fine on my desktop to Android. I have the following code segment:

```
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;
// ...
XMLReader p = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
```

At the last line I get the following exception:

```
Can't create default XMLReader; is system property org.xml.sax.driver set?
```

When I was testing the code on desktop, it was working fine. Why am I getting this exception on Android and how can I fix it? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by following [Parsing an XML File Using SAX (The Java™ Tutorials > Java API for XML Processing (JAXP) > Simple API for XML)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

Answer (score 12):

My solution was including the following code in my MainActivity:

```
System.setProperty("org.xml.sax.driver","org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");
```

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into the same issue while porting some code to Android. I found that creating my own factory and parser seems to work.

I'd try replacing this:

```
XMLReader p = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
```

With this:

```
SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser newSAXParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader p = newSAXParser.getXMLReader();
```

Hope this helps :)