# OpenNLP in Android get invalid format inputstream

Tags: java, android, opennlp

I'm using OpenNLP to develop TTS in Android. 
i put every config files in /assets/ directory. 
and get InputStream from AssetManager. but the problem is when the InputStream as input parameter in initializing a POSModel,that throws a InvalidFormatException.

Codes below:

1.get InputStream.

```
public static InputStream getStream(String propertyName)
            throws FileNotFoundException, MaryConfigurationException        {
        InputStream stream = null; 
        String propertyValue = getProperty(propertyName);
    if (propertyValue == null) {
        return null; 
    } else {
        try {

            stream =     (InputStream)Globals.context.getResources().getAssets().open(propertyValue); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return stream;

}
```

new a Pos tagger.

```
    InputStream modelStream = (InputStream)MaryProperties.needStream(propertyPrefix+"model");    //here should return the InputStream of en-pos-maxent.bin
        try {
            tagger = new POSTaggerME(new POSModel(modelStream));  
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here gets the InvalidFormatException,

```
opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException: The profile data stream has an invalid format
```

does anyone have some idea?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your method is returning the right *type* of `InputStream` - OpenNLP's going to be looking for a `FileInputStream` or `ByteArrayInputStream`. The error seems to point to this as the issue. The way you're getting the actual file to open also seems a little suspect - your comment says that you're opening `en-pos-maxent.bin`, but `propertyPrefix+"model"` doesn't look like the way I'd open a file with that name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, propertyPrefix+"model" was just a attribute in a config file, and the value is en-pos-maxent.bin.     for now i don't know why, but it seems run though these step.  But, the new tagger get the nullpoint :(

Answer (score 0):

I caught a similar InvalidFormatException exception. Tracing farther showed the function that was failing was

org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165477/porting-to-android-why-am-i-getting-cant-create-default-xmlreader-is-system) solved it.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)