# InvalidFormatException Android

Tags: java, android, exception, opennlp

I get an error in this code which makes the model object null and crashes the app. It looks like it should work but it doesn't in this case. This code works in a different part of the code when I get an inputstream of "en-sent.bin" for SentenceModel but with the this POSModel it gets this error. Any help is appreciated. Should be a simple fix.

Here is my code:

```
//sets up the part of speech tagger
public POSModel setupPOSTagger() {
    InputStream modelIn = null;
    POSModel model = null;
    try {
        modelIn = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.en_pos_maxent);
        model = new POSModel(modelIn);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Model loading failed, handle the error
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (modelIn != null) {
            try {
                modelIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
08-04 14:15:44.169 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err: opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException: The profile data stream has an invalid format!
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.dictionary.serializer.DictionarySerializer.create(DictionarySerializer.java:224)
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.postag.POSDictionary.create(POSDictionary.java:293)
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.postag.POSTaggerFactory$POSDictionarySerializer.create(POSTaggerFactory.java:151)
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.postag.POSTaggerFactory$POSDictionarySerializer.create(POSTaggerFactory.java:147)
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.finishLoadingArtifacts(BaseModel.java:328)
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.loadModel(BaseModel.java:256)
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:179)
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel.<init>(POSModel.java:105)
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.WordCounter.setupPOSTagger(WordCounter.java:101)
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.WordCounter.makeSentences(WordCounter.java:53)
08-04 14:15:44.175 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.Article.<init>(Article.java:19)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.ArticleReceiver.receiveNewsArticles(ArticleReceiver.java:89)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.ArticleReceiver.<init>(ArticleReceiver.java:37)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.MainActivity.fetchNews(MainActivity.java:114)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.gigstudios.newssummary.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:52)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err: Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Can't create default XMLReader; is system property org.xml.sax.driver set?
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:156)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.dictionary.serializer.DictionarySerializer.create(DictionarySerializer.java:219)
08-04 14:15:44.176 12476-12476/com.gigstudios.newssummary W/System.err:     ... 21 more
```

Comment: This `en_pos_maxent` file... What does it look like?

Comment: @cricket_007 what do you mean? it's a bin file in the raw directory and it's needed for the POSModel

Comment: Just read the error.. `The profile data stream has an invalid format`. I was asking what type of file it was because this library you have cannot read it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [porting to Android: why am I getting "Can't create default XMLReader; is system property org.xml.sax.driver set?"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165477/porting-to-android-why-am-i-getting-cant-create-default-xmlreader-is-system)